# Javascript redirect to a page with jquery tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs, window.location

'I have a page where after an AJAX and js function runs I need to reload the page and go to a specific JqueryUI tab.  (in this case the tab is 'tabs-b')  (jquery-ui-1.8.20)

This code reloads the page, but does not go to the tabs-b  (its at the default)

```
var formID = 'tabs-b';
window.location.href=$('survey1.php','#'+formID).val();
window.location.reload(true);
```

I have also tried this to the same effect:

```
window.location.href='survey1.php#tabs-b';
window.location.reload(true);
```

however when I just type it into the browser it works.  I am stumped.  I am fairly new to js so it may be a noob syntax error, but I have not found any other people with the same issue.

Comment: are you using http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Comment: Yes - edited to reflect this

Comment: use document onload function at the place of window reload, because it will call when document loads not a window

Comment: can you explain? not sure how that would work here. This is a function where they delete and item, and I need to refresh the page to re-run a dozen or so functions on the page afterwards

Comment: http://codes.codedigest.com/FAQ/40-What-is-the-difference-between-Body-OnLoad-and-jQuery-document-ready%28%29-Event-.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you code you do not need `window.location.href` and `window.location.reload`. `reload (true`) will fetch from the server the current page based upon the existing url.

Just use `window.location.href`

Comment: I tried it, but it did not work;  did not reload the page (to refresh data)

Comment: window.location.href='survey1.php#tabs-b';

Comment: After this code are you returning false? or is some other code affecting the outcome?

Comment: Hmm, I can not see any difference between `window.location.href='survey1.php#tabs-b';` and typing it in the browser.  When the page reloads is the hashtag still on the url?

Comment: I am rethinking how to manage this function to possibly code around this and not need a refresh, just call the functions that are needed to be re-run.  More of a pain, not modular, but maybe faster for user.

Comment: So, this means there is a problem with your survey1.php.  It is not correctly capturing (or re-adding) the value of the hashtag

Comment: That is possible.  Its a bear of a page, over 3700 lines of code, not counting includes.

Comment: must be a bug in survey1.php - I decided to solve the problem another way.  Thanks for the help.  Will have to hunt down the bug later.